# Getting a string of numbers from a text box, then splitting them. Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a string of numbers the user enters into a textbox, then split them by comma. I take those values and find the min, max, and total. I just can't seem to get the values from the text box properly.

This is my code:

```
var numbers = document.querySelector("#numbers").value;

function tabTwo()
{
    var i;
    var min = 0;
    var max = 0;
    var total = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <= numbers.length; i++)
    {
        var numbersSplit = Number(numbers.split(","));

        min = i;
        max = i;

        if (numbersSplit[i] < min)
        {
            min = numbersSplit[i];       
        }

        if (numbers[i] > max)
        {
            max = numbersSplit[i];
        }

        total += numbersSplit[i];
    }

    totalDiv.innerHTML = total;
    smallestDiv.innerHTML = min;
    biggestDiv.innerHTML = max;
}
```

Comment: In your code min and max will have the same value because of min = i; and max = 1. Why you don't give value to max?

Comment: If you could also post your HTML that would be helpful, but it appears to me that you want to loop over your `numbersSplit` variable (without wrapping it up in `Number()`), as that is going to produce an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your code doesn't show that your function is ever being called
2. Your function splits the input value into an array, but it's an
   array of strings, not numbers because the "T" in HTML stands for
   "Text". All data in HTML is strings (no matter what it may look like
   to you). The array values must be converted to numbers before you can do math.

**Having said that, this is much simpler than what you are doing.**

When you split the input value, you have an array of strings. They must be converted to numbers to do math on them and the **[`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method is perfect for returning a new array based on enumerating an array and running a callback function on each value it finds in the first array.

The built-in JavaScript **[`Math`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math)** object has **[`max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)** and **[`min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)** methods that will get you those answers with no looping or `if/then` logic needed.

Then the **[`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** method can reduce an array to a single value based on a callback function that you specify.

**NOTES:**

- You didn't supply your HTML as well, but something has got to call
  your `tabTwo()` function. In the code below, I've set that up so that
  when the input loses the focus (just click into it and then hit
  <kbd>TAB</kbd>), the function runs.
- `Math.min` and `Math.max` are methods that normally expect a list of
  arguments. To have them work on an array, you can use a **["destructuring assignment"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)** (`...`) to pull the array values out into a list of values, suitable for passing to `max` and `min`.
- It's not a good idea to set your variables directly to a DOM object
  property, like `value` because if you ever want to access any other
  property of the object, you'll have to scan the DOM all over again to
  find it. Instead, set your variable(s) to the object itself and then
  simply access any property you need when you need it.
- `.innerHTML` is for when the string you are setting/getting contains
  HTML. It invokes the HTML parser and parses that string. This is a
  waste of resources if the string doesn't contain any HTML. In those
  cases, use `.textContent` instead, which does not invoke the HTML
  parser.

```js
// Get your DOM object references, just once.
var numbers = document.querySelector("#numbers");
var smallest = document.querySelector("#smallest");
var biggest = document.querySelector("#biggest");
var tot = document.querySelector("#total");

// Set up event listner for when the element loses focus
numbers.addEventListener("blur", tabTwo);

function tabTwo() { 
  // Split the value into an array and then return a new array of those 
  // string values converted to numbers
  var nums = numbers.value.split(",").map((num) => { return +num });

  // No need to reinvent the wheel here, use JavaScript to do this stuff:
  smallest.textContent = Math.min(...nums);
  biggest.textContent = Math.max(...nums);
  tot.textContent = nums.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
}
```

```html
<input id="numbers" value="3,5,7,9">
<div>Smallest: <span id="smallest"></span></div>
<div>Biggest: <span id="biggest"></span></div>
<div>Total: <span id="total"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers = document.querySelector("#numbers").value;

function tabTwo() {

  var i;
  var min = 0;
  var max = 0;
  var total = 0;
  var numbersSplit = numbers.split(",");


  for (i = 0; i <= numbersSplit.length; i++) {
    var currentNum = parseInt(numbersSplit[i]);

    if (currentNum < min) {
      min = currentNum;
    }

    if (currentNum > max) {
      max = currentNum;

    }

    total += currentNum;

  }

  totalDiv.innerHTML = total;
  smallestDiv.innerHTML = min;
  biggestDiv.innerHTML = max;

}
```

Comment: I have not tested this.

Answer (score 0):

Use parseInt to convert a string to an int

```
    var numbers = document.querySelector("#numbers").value;
    var arr = numbers.split(",");
    var min = parseInt(arr[0]);
    var max = parseInt(arr[0]);
    var total = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i<arr.length;i++){
        var element = parseInt(arr[i])
        if(element < min){
            min = element
         }
        if(element > max){
            max = element
        }
        total += element
     }
```